# Operator norm of inverse of a positive balanced matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a $d\times d$ matrix with all the coordinates strictly positive. Also assume that $A$ is balanced, i.e, all the row sums of $A$ are exactly equal to $1$. Does there exist a constant $c>0$ which does not depend on $A$ and $\|A^{-1}\|\le c\|A\|$ ?

Note: We can work with any norm since the underlying vector space is finite dimensional.

Comment: Check out $A=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this family matrices
$$
A_t=\pmatrix{1-t & t\\1-2t & 2t}
$$
it fulfills your conditions for $t\in (0,1/2)$. For such values it is invertible. Moreover, $(A_t)_{t\in(0,1/2)}$ is uniformly bounded for all norms you can imagine. However $\|A_t^{-1}\|\to\infty$ for $t\searrow0$.